# Like-based Recommendations

Tags: algorithm, recommendation-engine

I'm curious what algorithms are out there for like-based recommendations. What I mean by this is people can "like" something but they cannot "unlike" something. What kind of recommendation algorithms are there for such a scenario.

I had one idea but I don't think its scalable. My idea was to create a graph where each likable item has an edge to each other likable item with an edge capacity of the number of users that liked both items in common. Then to make recommendations for a certain user, you augment the graph so that the user is a source node with infinite edges to all the items the user likes. All the items the user hasn't liked have an edge with infinite capacity to the destination node. Then run maximum flow using Ford-Fulkerson and the recommendations can be sorted based on the edge flows at the destination. However, upon thinking about it, a graph with 1000 items or more can quickly get out of hand.

I've thought about other systems like collaborative filters, but I'm not sure they'll work very well considering there is no down-vote or multiple scales of liking. Thus a "dislike" is indistinguishable from a "haven't liked yet".

I'd appreciate any ideas or resources.

Comment: there is a big difference between "seen and didn't like" to "did'nt see". do you have data if the user have seen an item or not? seen and didn't like is sometimes used as a weak "dislike"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some points you can use:

1. There is a big difference between "seen and didn't like" to "didn't see". Often, a "seen and didn't like" is used as a weak "dislike", and then you can use collaborative filtering.
2. You can still find "similar users" based on likes, and based on a set of similar users (who tend to like similar things) - you can suggest items they liked. You can determine two users are "similar" if the sets of items they liked has a high [Jaccard similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) (for example), and recommend items liked by a large portion of "similar" users.

You may search the literature for more alternatives, this is a hot topic on [www conference](http://www.www2015.it/) for the last few years, and new methods are always evolving.

Comment: I see. So using jaccard similarity, each recommendation costs roughly O(N*M) where N is the number of users and M is the number of items. Realistically, performance will go as 2*M is the average number of liked items or something like that. Now considering maybe a million users and 1000 items liked by each user, we may need something slightly faster. An incremental approach would cost O(N) on each new "like". I suppose this is where collaborative filtering starts to flourish. Any thoughts?